Is it possible to get the return type of a function - when it's called with particular parameters?
This relates to using generated apis (in this case openapi-fetch), where we might have some code like:
import {paths} from "./the-generated-types"; 
import createClient from "openapi-fetch"; 

const client = createClient<paths>(); 


// Now I can we can use the client like: 
client.GET("/blogposts/{post_id}", {
  params: {
    path: { post_id: "my-post" },
    query: { version: 2 },
  },
});


// But, for the purpose of code structure/modularity we want to define a module interface like: 

export async function getBlogPostById(args: ??) : Promise< ???> {

} 


For demonstrations sake I have some typings like this:

type Paths = "/a" | "/b" | "/c";

type PathToMethodMap = {
  "/a": {
    GET: (query: {search: string}) => {id: string; value: string}; 
  },
    "/b": {
    GET: (query: {search: string}) => {id: string; value: string}; 
  }
      "/c": {
    GET: (query: {search: string}) => {id: string; value: string}; 
    PATCH: (body: {id: string, value: string}) => {id: string; value: string}; 
  }
}


function getClient<T extends Paths>(path: T ) : PathToMethodMap[T] {

}

getClient("/a").GET({search: "hello"})
getClient("/c").PATCH({id: "a", value: "b"})

Now I know that I can implement my function like this:
function patchC(...args: Parameters<PathToMethodMap["/c"]["PATCH"]>)
: ReturnType<PathToMethodMap["/c"]["PATCH"]>{

}

However, in real life these typings are more convoluted and unwieldy.
What I'd like to do is a typing like this:
function alternativePatchC(...args: Parameters<typeof getClient[WHEN CALLED WITH "/c"]["PATCH"]>) 
: ReturnType<typeof getClient[WHEN CALLED WITH "/c"]["PATCH"]>{
  
}

Is such a thing possible?

You’re looking for “call types” and they are not part of the language. I’ll find the relevant GitHub issue when I get a chance.

It's https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40179.  See the linked q/a for more information.

Dunno if this will help, but you can get the same result without calling the function, using ReturnType for a function with generics can solve the problem, you won't ever need to call the function,  for example, you can use:
function getClient<T extends Paths>(path: T ) : PathToMethodMap[T]{};

// Identical to the one you wrote above
function alternativePatchC(...args: Parameters<ReturnType<typeof getClient<"/c">>["PATCH"]>) 
: ReturnType<ReturnType<typeof getClient<"/c">>["PATCH"]>{};


Isn't that what I'm doing in my example?

like i said it's identical to the code you wrote, but instead of directly using the type, you are using the function's return type with the parameter you wanted to provide, why do you need to call a function when you can simply use ReturnType of the function with generics?
